# How to use MERGE keyword in pl/sql?

Tags: plsql

I am updating a table, but I keep getting follwing error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "MERGE"
LINE 3: MERGE into
```

when i try to use a merge statement. I don't see anything obvious wrong with the syntax. can  someone point out the obivous

```
MERGE into Table2 t2
using (select name, max(id) max_id from Table1 t1 group by name ) t1
on (t2.project_name=t1.name)
when matched then update set projectid=max_id where status='ongoing' ;
```

Table1

```
1  | alpha           | 2021 | 
2  | groundwork      | 2020 | 
3  | NETOS           | 2021 | 
5  | WebOPD          | 2019 | 

Table2 

id | name  | year | status     | project name      | projectID 
1  |  john | 2021  | ongoing    | alpha            | 1 
2  | linda | 2021  | completed  | NETOS            | 3 
3  | pat   | 2021  | WebOPD     | completed        | 5
4  | tom   | 2021  | ongoing    | alpha            | 1
```

version : PostgreSQL 13.6

Comment: btw Oracle PL/SQL, if that's what you're using (unlikely perhaps since the error message doesn't start with PLS- or ORA-), is a programming language that only really supports MERGE in the sense that it supports embedded SQL statements. A standard Oracle SQL statement like MERGE should work fine. If it doesn't, then you'll probably need to post a simplified test case that we can try for ourselves.

Answer (score 2):

The last line in your message says you use **PostgreSQL**. Tag you used (`plsql`) means **Oracle**. Which one is it, after all? I presume former, but - syntax you used is Oracle.

[MERGE](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/attachment/23520/sql-merge.html) documentation for PostgreSQL says that

- `INTO` can't be used
- no parenthesis for `ON` clause
- `WHERE` clause can't be used

See if something like this helps:

```
MERGE Table2 t2
using (select t1.name, 
              max(t1.id) max_id 
       from Table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t2.project_name = t1.name
       where t2.status = 'ongoing'
       group by name 
      ) x 
on t2.project_name = x.name
when matched then update set 
  t2.projectid = x.max_id ;
```

Comment: it is postgreSql . I did run into the same error SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "MERGE"
  Position: 1